# Firebase chat app with chatbot

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am creating iOS app where i am using firebase to connect customer to team for first some messages I need it will reply automatically and after that I need customer can chat with our customer support team any tutorial from scratch.

Comment: This is a very large project you are embarking on.  Break you problem into smaller parts and ask separate, clear questions!

Comment: Please do some R & D on your project and ask about the problem if you have?

Comment: look at these examples 1. https://github.com/firebase/firechat-ios 2. https://github.com/google/ios-chatbot 3. https://github.com/firebase/ios-swift-chat-example 4. https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2

I did not run these code but seems good